# Python: remplazar numeros con otros numeros

Tags: python, replace

estoy haciendo un encriptor personalizado cambiando una letra del abecedario por otra con `.replace()`, funciona perfecto el abecedario y me imprime lo que debe ser pero los numeros no, como lo puedo solucionar?

---

```
def encriptar(palabra):
    x1 = palabra.replace("a", "m")
    x2 = x1.replace("b", "k")
    x3 = x2.replace("c", "w")
    x4 = x3.replace("d", "a")
    x5 = x4.replace("e", "y")
    x6 = x5.replace("f", "x")
    x7 = x6.replace("g", "h")
    x8 = x7.replace("h", "p")
    x9 = x8.replace("i", "q")
    x10 = x9.replace("j", "f")
    x11 = x10.replace("k", "s")
    x12 = x11.replace("l", "d")
    x13 = x12.replace("m", "j")
    x14 = x13.replace("n", "t")
    x15 = x14.replace("o", "v")
    x16 = x15.replace("p", "r")
    x17 = x16.replace("q", "f")
    x18 = x17.replace("r", "u")
    x19 = x18.replace("s", "o")
    x20 = x19.replace("t", "i")
    x21 = x20.replace("u", "e")
    x22 = x21.replace("v", "g")
    x23 = x22.replace("w", "c")
    x24 = x23.replace("x", "n")
    x25 = x24.replace("y", "l")
    x26 = x25.replace("z", "b")

    #numeros
    x27 = x26.replace("0", "3")
    x28 = x27.replace("1", "7")
    x29 = x28.replace("2", "9")
    x30 = x29.replace("3", "0")
    x31 = x30.replace("4", "2")
    x32 = x31.replace("5", "8")
    x33 = x32.replace("6", "5")
    x34 = x33.replace("7", "1")
    x35 = x34.replace("8", "4")
    x36 = x35.replace("9", "6")
    print(x36)

def desencriptar():
    pass

encriptar("1234567890")
```

Comment: Probé tu código y me dio `1602451460`. ¿Cual debiera ser el resultado correcto? Edita tu pregunta y agrega esa información.

Comment: deberia ser 7902851463, el 1 se remplaza con un 7, el 2 se remplaza con un 9 etc, pero el 0 se queda en 0

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que vas haciendo cada replace "por turnos". Entonces primero reemplazas el 0 por 3. Pero más adelante reemplazas los 3 por 0, por lo que no obtienes el resultado buscado. De hecho, el cifrado de las letras tampoco funcionará correctamente, ya que por ejemplo primero cambias la "a" por "m", pero más adelante cambias la "m" por "j", por lo que al final las "aes" quedan como "jotas" en vez de "emes".

Lo que necesitas es una forma de hacer todos los cambios "a la vez" en un solo replace por así decir. Esta funcionalidad te la da `str.translate()`. Para usarlo tienes que crear antes una "tabla de traducción" mediante `str.maketrans()`.

Usando estas cosas, tu código se reduce a un par de líneas:

```
def encriptar(txt):
  cifra = str.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 
                        "mkwayxhpqfsdjtvrfuoiegcnlb3790285146")
  return txt.translate(cifra)
```

Y puedes verificar que funciona:

```
encriptar("1234567890")
```

Sale:

```
7902851463
```

### Bonus

La función desencriptar es análoga, intercambiando las cadenas usadas para crear la tabla de traducción.

```
def desencriptar(txt):
  cifra = str.maketrans("mkwayxhpqfsdjtvrfuoiegcnlb3790285146", 
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
  return txt.translate(cifra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Analicemos una versión simple del problema:

```
def encriptar(palabra):
    #numeros
    x27 = palabra.replace("0", "3")
    x28 = x27.replace("1", "7")
    x29 = x28.replace("2", "9")
    x30 = x29.replace("3", "0")
    x31 = x30.replace("4", "2")
    x32 = x31.replace("5", "8")
    x33 = x32.replace("6", "5")
    x34 = x33.replace("7", "1")
    x35 = x34.replace("8", "4")
    x36 = x35.replace("9", "6")
    print(x36)

print(encriptar("1234567890"))
```

produce:

```
1602451460
```

lo que es un error, ya que el resultado debe tener dígitos sin repetición.

El problema es que estas aplicando cambios sobre dígitos ya modificados. Por ejemplo,

```
print(encriptar("1"))
```

en la primera linea se convierte "1" por "7", y luego, más abajo, conviertes "7" en "1".

Una solución algorítmica es procesar por letras la entrada, produciendo en paralelo la salida.

Primero definimos un diccionario. Su llave es la letra/dígito/caracter de entrada, su valor es la letra/dígito/caracter de salida:

```
tabla = {
    "0": "3",
    "1": "7",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "0",
    "4": "2",
    "5": "8",
    "6": "5",
    "7": "1",
    "8": "4",
    "9": "6"
}
```

Usando comprensión de listas vamos sacando cada dígito de la palabra recibida. Usamos ese digito para extraer el reemplazo de la tabla.

El resultado es una lista de digitos de reemplazos, que unimos con `join`

```
def encriptar(palabra):
    salida = [tabla[digito] for digito in palabra]
    return ''.join(salida)

print(encriptar("1234567890"))
```

produce:

```
7902851463
```